# The name 'TempData' Does not exist in the current context .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, tempdata

I'm working in a .NET Core application in Visual Studio 2017 and in all my views I'm facing the error "The name 'TempData' Does not exist in the current context", but in the controllers it's normal.

[image]

Anyone had this error?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error when running your app (Executing this view code) ? or is just the IDE giving a warning ?

Comment: @Shyju It's the IDE giving that error.

Comment: Are your files located in the `Views` or `Pages` folder?

Comment: In Project dependency of your project in NuGet pacakge is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Assembly available?